# thread_guard vs scoped_thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, c++14

In the book

> "C++ Concurrency In Action" by Anthony Williams

you can find the following two snippet of code (I have introduced some slight modifications):

Snippet 1:

```
class thread_guard
{
    std::thread& t;
    public:
    explicit thread_guard(std::thread& t_): t(t_){}
    ~thread_guard()
    {
        if(t.joinable())
    {
        t.join();
    }
    }
    thread_guard(thread_guard const&)=delete;
    thread_guard& operator=(thread_guard const&)=delete;
};

void my_func()
{
    for(int j = 0; j < 1000; ++j)
    {
        cout << "\n " << j;
    }
}

void f()
{
    std::thread t1(my_func);
    thread_guard g(t1);
    do_something_in_current_thread();
}

int main()
{
    f();
    return 0;
}
```

Going on you can find

Snippet 2:

```
class scoped_thread
{
    std::thread t;
    public:
    explicit scoped_thread(std::thread t_):    t(std::move(t_))
    {
        if(!t.joinable())
        throw std::logic_error(“No thread”);
    }
    ~scoped_thread()
    {
        t.join();
    }
    scoped_thread(scoped_thread const&)=delete;
    scoped_thread& operator=(scoped_thread const&)=delete;
};

void my_func()
{
    for(int j = 0; j < 1000; ++j)
    {
        cout << "\n " << j;
    }
}

void f()
{
   scoped_thread st1(thread(my_func));

   thread t2(my_func);
   scoped_thread st2(move(t2));

   do_something_in_current_thread();
}

int main()
{
    f();
    return 0;
}
```

I'm not sure that I can really appreciate the real difference between these 2 snippets.

The only difference that I can see is that in Snippet 1 the instance of `thread_guard` does not take ownership of the thread `t1` (unlike a `scoped_thread` object) and so it could be possible call `t1.join()` but this is not a problem when `~thread_guard()` is executed.

So: where is (if exists) the advantage of Snippet 2?

Comment: IMO, the text of the book explains the purpose of `scope_thread` as an enhancement of `thread_guard`:
"you can build on the `thread_guard` class from listing 2.3 and have it take ownership of the thread. This avoids any unpleasant consequences should the `thread_guard` object outlive the thread it was referencing, and it also means that no one else can join or detach the thread once ownership has been transferred into the object. Because this would primarily be aimed at ensuring that threads are completed before a scope is exited, I named this class `scoped_thread`..."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both types are meant to block on destruction (e.g. scope exit) until a thread finishes. The difference is in the ownership of the `thread` object.

`thread_guard` doesn't own the `thread` itself; there may be more than one `thread_guard` waiting on the same `thread`. This also means that the `thread` object must be alive as long as any `thread_guard` refers to it. If the referenced thread has already been joined when a `thread_guard` object is destroyed, it won't block or produce an error (as opposed to just calling `join` on a thread that is not joinable).

`scoped_thread`, on the other hand, takes ownership of the `thread` instance, and therefore also controls its lifetime. You would use it whenever you want to own the thread you want to wait on, e.g. as a data member.

Ultimately, which one you use is a question of semantics: do you want to wait on a thread someone else owns (then you also have to make sure there are no lifetime issues), or do you want a `thread` object that blocks when it gets destroyed, without you having to `join` it first.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of functionality these both implementation are capable to server the purpose, the only difference i can see in these two implementation is, `Snippet 2` can accept both `lvalue(glvalue)` and `rvalue(prvalue)` but `Snippet 1` can't accept `rvalue(prvalue)` as constructor argument. For example consider following code,

```
std::thread getThread()
{
    return std::thread([](){ std::cout<< __PRETTY_FUNCTION__<< std::endl;});
}

int main( int , char *[])
{
    thread_guard g( getThread());
    return 0;
}
```

Now if you compile this code, compile will give following error,

```
 error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type ‘std::thread&’ to an rvalue of type ‘std::remove_reference<std::thread&>::type’ {aka ‘std::thread’}
     explicit thread_guard(std::thread _t): t(std::move( _t)){ std::cout<< __PRETTY_FUNCTION__<< std::endl;}
```

But `snippet 2` implementation will work fine.