# Why is copying or assigning objects of this class considered dangerous?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

From "C++ Concurrency in Action" by Anthony Williams.

The author defines a `thread_guard` class which, is passed a reference to a `std::thread` upon construction, and upon destruction, attempts to `join()` that same thread.

Here is the definition

```
class thread_guard
{
    std::thread& t;
    public:
        explicit thread_guard(std::thread& t_):t(_t){}
    ~thread_guard()
    {
        if(t.joinable())
        {
           t.join();
        }
    }
    thread_guard(thread_guard const&)=delete;  // why?
    thread_guard operator=(thread_guard const&)=delete;  // why?
};

struct func; // function object, definition not included here
void f()
{ 
    int some_local_state = 0;
    func my_func(some_local_state); // passing in a local variable
    std::thread t(my_func);

    // ensure that thread finishes before exiting f()
    thread_guard tg(t);  
    do_something_in_current_thread();
}
```

My question is why are the copy constructor and assignment operator disallowed (with `delete`)?
The author says that copying would be dangerous because the `thread_guard` copy "might then outlive the scope of the thread it was joining".
But I'm confused - isn't that a risk anyway, even with the original object (that the object will outlive the scope of the thread)? Isn't that why there is a check in the destructor, `if t.joinable()`?

What fundamental thing have I missed here.

(Related: [thread_guard vs scoped_thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56497350/thread-guard-vs-scoped-thread))

Comment: The thread guard copy could be created in another thread. Then the original thread it holds gets joined by the original thread_guard....

Comment: ... and the thread_guard copy checks if the original thread is joinable() before going out of scope... where is the problem?

Comment: `if(t.joinable()) t.join();` is not atomic, that's the problem. Both threads may complete that check , then try to join.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `std::thread` object that the `thread_guard` guards is held *by reference*. Therefore, if the `thread_guard` object outlives the `std::thread` object, then there is a dangling reference, and the call to `t.joinable()` is undefined behaviour.

Making `thread_guard` non-copyable makes it harder to end up in this scenario: since the `std::thread` object and `thread_guard` are likely local-scope variables, then in order to pass the thread to the guard, the thread must be constructed first, which means it will be destroyed afterwards in most circumstances.

Note: none of this is about the thread itself, purely about the `std::thread` *object*.

If there are multiple `thread_guard` objects for the same `std::thread` object, the first to be destroyed will call `t.join()` if necessary, and the second will see the thread has already been joined and do nothing.

If the `std::thread` object has no thread whether because it was default constructed, has already been joined or detached, or its thread was moved to another `std::thread` object, then the `thread_guard` destructor does nothing.

Answer (score 2):

The explanation given isn't the most compelling reason (imo).

There should only ever be *one* `thread_guard` for each thread. Making it uncopyable means that it is difficult to *accidentally* have two guards of the same thread.

The expected use case is that both the thread and the guard are automatic storage duration objects living in the same scope, with the guard joining the thread just before it is destroyed. There isn't a need to copy the guard